# EXTBASE: An object of class "Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorage" could not be converted to a plain value

Tags: typo3, extbase

After saving a model with a 1:n relation in the extension builder, this error shows up:

```
An object of class "Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorage" could not be converted to a plain value.
```

What needs to be set in the extension builder to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In the extension builder for that model, the value of `Object type` needs to be set to `Entity` instead of `Value object`.
Or in your generated model class check if it extends `Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity`.